# Link to deliver a mailer in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

I have a link that, when clicked, should deliver an email by using an action defined in a controller. I am not setting the path correctly however:

```
= link_to "Email", quote_deliver_customer_mailer_path
```

quotes_controller

```
def deliver_customer_mailer(quote)
  @quote = quote
  CustomerMailer.estimate(@quote).deliver
end
```

routes.rb

```
resources :quotes do
  get :deliver_customer_mailer
end
```

I get the following error message `No route matches {:action=>"deliver_customer_mailer", :controller=>"quotes"}`. A) What would be the right way to create that link. B) Is there a better way I should be building this? Thanks.

### Update

Ah, I needed to pass a value into the path... `quote_deliver_customer_mailer_path(quote)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must create a method in controller then set route to it and from controller send an email. You can't do it from view.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've updated the question after trying your suggestion.